# Create rectangle below a button with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS based 'button' like this:

[image]

The blue is just a background, so it's only about the text "Welkom" and the rectangle displayed below.

Whenever it's active or hovered over it should display a rectangle BELOW the button.

HTML: (This is the button)

```
<li><a href="#" id="welkom">Welkom</a></li>
```

Comment: True but I didn't formulate it properly there, plus I haven't gotten any feedback ever since. Requested removal for the other thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the below is your HTML:

```
 <li><a href="#" id="welkom">Welkom</a></li>
```

Then you can do this:

```
li:hover,li:active{
    border-bottom:3px solid blue; /*change blue to the color you want*/
}
```

### [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uHt56/4/)

---

Fiddle in response to comment: [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/uHt56/5/)

The above uses box-align property(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-align.asp) to center the bottom border(without requiring adjustment) but it will not work in IE9 and below

---

[Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/uHt56/6/) : Will work in all browsers but you will have to adjust the bottom at the center using relative positioning for both `li` and `a` tag within it.

Comment: Ah great, that works fine. But can I also let it cointain a specific width?

Comment: yes you can @luikstruik

Comment: How exactly? And maybe possible to center it below the button as well?

Comment: I will add a fiddle in 5 minutes

Comment: Awesome, trying border-height and border-width but that does the same thing for me.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Appreciate it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that on :hover with a border-bottom:
But you may and a border already without the hover so avoid jumping.

```
a {
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

a:hover {
  border-color: blue
}
```

The code above is not all you may need.

-Sven

EDIT: as you see the other answer, U ay do that on the list element directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
simple just follow below code:

HTML:

<div class="link"><a href="#">Welkom</a></div>

CSS:

.link { background-color:#379AE6; width:100%; padding:8px; padding-bottom:16px; }

.link a{ font-family:arial; text-decoration:none; color:#fff;
    }

.link a:hover{ border-bottom:8px solid #6BBBF8; padding-bottom:8px;
    }
```